# Rank of a bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have to prove that a bilinear form $B$ has full rank, and I would like to know some ideas on how to prove that.

Can anyone give an idea?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* Show that a bilinear map is non-degenerate if and only if its matrix representation has full rank.

Comment: The problem is that is very hard to find a matrix representation (I am working with a particular bilineal form, but i want some alternative ideas instead of asking for the solution, because i would like to think the problem by my self

Comment: @Dimitri Can you prove that it's non-degenerate?  (That is $\langle x,y\rangle = 0$ for all $y$ implies that $x=0$.)

Comment: Yes, that is what i try to do, with a little help and work i think i almost have it :)

Answer (score 1):

So what I've long time known as Gaussian reduction (not Gaussian elimination, other technique) is now Lagrange's reduction... Maybe it's me. I'm sure there is another name more popular in the english speaking world. And I'm sure someone will tell us.

Anyway, [here](http://www.solitaryroad.com/c138.html) is a place where you can find an example, if not a full theory. Note that it is based on the square completion method.

And [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Lagrange_method) is another one, with just enough theory.

Once you have performed the reduction. Count the nonzero coefficients. It is your rank.